# Stored procedure if no records for the start date and end date?

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure as below:

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[GetSleepData]
    @period varchar(30),
    @fitbit varchar(6),
    @customdate datetime null,
    @startdate datetime null,
    @enddate datetime null

    as


    if(@period = 'week')
    Begin
    Set @customdate = Getdate()
        Select Sleepkey, fitbitid,totalMinutesAsleep,totalSleepRecords,totalTimeInBed, datetime from sleep where fitbitid = @fitbit and
        datetime  <=@customdate  datetime= @customdate - 7
    End

    else if(@period = 'month')
    Begin
    Set @customdate = Getdate()
        Select Sleepkey, fitbitid,totalMinutesAsleep,totalSleepRecords,totalTimeInBed, datetime from sleep where fitbitid = @fitbit and 
         datetime<= @customdate and datetime >= @customdate - 30
    End
```

this is working fine. I need to add an if clause to the select statement. it should be like this:

if there is no record for the startDate and/or endDate, it should add a record with zero values in it.

Comment: You should look at this article which discusses queries like this with multiple execution paths. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/09/15/multiple-execution-paths/

Comment: Why do you compare strings instead of dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you can combine your statement to one `SELECT`.

Second consider using  `DATEADD(d, -number, @customdate)` for substraction days from date instead of `@customdate - 7`:

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[GetSleepData]
    @period      varchar(30),
    @fitbit      varchar(6),
    @customdate  datetime   = null,
    @startdate   datetime   = null,
    @enddate     datetime   = null
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- you should here validate @period like
-- IF @period NOT IN ('week', 'month')
--     RAISEERROR(....) /THROW ...;

SET @customdate = GETDATE();

SELECT Sleepkey, fitbitid,totalMinutesAsleep,
       totalSleepRecords,totalTimeInBed, [datetime]
INTO #temp 
FROM sleep 
WHERE fitbitid = @fitbit 
  AND [datetime] <= @customdate
  AND [datetime] >= @customdate - ( CASE @period 
                                   WHEN 'week' THEN 7
                                   WHEN 'month' THEN 30
                                   ELSE NULL --??? what if period is different
                                 END;

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #temp)
BEGIN
  SELECT 0 AS Sleepkey, 0 AS fitbitid, 0 AS totalMinutesAsleep,
         0 AS totalSleepRecords, 0 AS totalTimeInBed, NULL AS [datetime]
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT Sleepkey, fitbitid,totalMinutesAsleep,
            totalSleepRecords,totalTimeInBed, [datetime]
    FROM #temp;
END

END
```

Do not name column like datatypes: `datetime` should be quoted `[datetime]`.